# Wordpress Footer Menus

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm making my first wordpress child theme. In my footer, i would like to be able to setup three different menus, but the problem is, it doenst work, it keeps using my "footer

This is my footer php

```
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
    <div class="site-info">

        <nav class="footer-colum1">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer'    );
            wp_nav_menu();
            ?>
        </nav>

        <nav class="footer-colum2">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer2'   );
            wp_nav_menu();

            ?>
        </nav>

        <nav class="footer-colum3">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu();
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer3'   );


            ?>
        </nav>

        <nav class="footer-colum4">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu();
            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer4'   );


            ?>
        </nav>
```

This is my functions php

```
        register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'aagaardefterskole'  ),
        'footer' => __('Footer Menu Colum 1'),
        'footer2' => __('Footer Menu Colum 2'),
        'footer3' => __('Footer Menu Colum 3'),
    ) );
```

So, how do i make my "footer2" show the ('Footer Menu Colum 2') and not the ('Footer Menu Colum 1')

Comment: `wp_nav_menu($args);`?

Answer (score 1):

First check how to call WordPress menu in the file [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).

You need different $args for different menus. They should not be repeat and will come before `wp_nav-menu()`.

```
    <nav class="footer-colum1">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer'    );
        wp_nav_menu($args);
        ?>
    </nav>

    <nav class="footer-colum2">
        <?php
        $args2 = array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer2'   );
        wp_nav_menu($args2);

        ?>
    </nav>

    <nav class="footer-colum3">
        <?php

        $args3 = array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer3'   );
        wp_nav_menu($args3);

        ?>
    </nav>

    <nav class="footer-colum4">
        <?php

        $args4 = array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer4'   );
        wp_nav_menu($args4);

        ?>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `$args` to `wp_nav_menu()`. You need to do:

```
...

<?php

$args = array(
   'theme_location' => 'footer2'
);
wp_nav_menu($args); ?>

...
```